# How do I get a css animation to only apply to specific images?

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to css, and wrote some simple code so that an image would get bigger when hovered on

The code I tried to put in was
`<style> .icon{ } img{ transition: transform .2s; } img:hover{ transform:scale(1.3); } </style>`

```
`<div class="icon"><img src="general-media/icons/abt.png"></div>`
```

I set the images I want to get bigger into the icon div, but every image gets bigger on hover, even when they're not in the div. How do i fix this?

Comment: It's because you set the transition and hover effect on `img`. So all `img` tags will transform. If you put the transition and hover on `.icon`, then any div with the class `icon` will transform.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the animated-image class is applied to the images you want to animate. The animation is a simple sliding-in effect, but you can replace it with any other animation you desire.

By using classes or IDs, you can precisely target specific elements on your webpage for styling and animations. Ensure that you use unique classes or IDs for your specific images to avoid unintended styling conflicts.

```
    .animated-image {
  /* Define your animation properties */
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  /* Add other animation properties as needed */
    }

    @keyframes slideIn {
    from {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    }
```